# Plotting a timeseries with multiple aggregates

Tags: python, plot, visualization, bokeh

I have a dataset that includes a timestamp and three columns with summary counts.  The dataset looks like this:

```
date_hour   children    adults  seniors
1/1/18 0:00 243 247 358
1/1/18 1:00 265 320 499
1/1/18 2:00 292 261 386
1/1/18 3:00 232 324 251
1/1/18 4:00 368 464 300
1/1/18 5:00 247 477 469
1/1/18 6:00 452 432 252
1/1/18 7:00 366 263 414
1/1/18 8:00 275 296 475
1/1/18 9:00 290 257 441
1/1/18 10:00    346 258 459
1/1/18 11:00    352 231 436
1/1/18 12:00    284 261 214
```

The data set is for a week and I'd like to build a visulization using pandas or similar that shows the data by hour as a stacked area.  I have not had any trouble doing this visualization as timeseries lines in Bokeh or as a pandas plot, but I just can't seem to figure out how to convert it to a stacked area cleanly and with the x axis summarized to the day.

[image: timeseries line womp womp]

The closest I can get to what I want is this:

```
%matplotlib inline
df = outcome
df = df.set_index('request_datetime_utc_60_minutes')
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df.plot.bar(stacked=True,figsize=(10,8))
```

I'm testing in Jupyter, and that produces this ugliness, still not a shaded area:

[image: more ugliness]

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of off-the-shelf area options that provide slightly different aesthetics. There is also the option to create a plot using subpots. Since what you have shown above reminds more of a stacked line plot, there is one below too. If you replace stacked=True with subplots=True you will get a plot similar to the second plot but unfilled.

```
from numpy.random import randint
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a df with a date-time index with data every hour
rng = pd.date_range('1/5/2018 00:00', periods=168, freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Children':randint(200, 300, 168),
                   'Adults': randint(250, 400, 168),
                   'Seniors': randint(200, 350, 168)}, index=rng)

df.plot.area()
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Number of Visitors')
plt.show()

df.plot.area(subplots=True)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Number of Visitors')
plt.show()

plt.figure()
plt.stackplot(df.index, df['Children'], df['Adults'], df['Seniors'], labels=df.columns)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Number of Visitors')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

plt.figure()
df[['Children', 'Adults', 'Seniors']].plot(stacked=True)
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Number of Visitors')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Really grateful for the help--this has gotten me right on track.

Comment: Excellent! You were very close anyway, but I thought I would give you different flavours of what you can do. I am glad it has worked for you.